# Выпуск видеочата №4 с @Pavel и @Rakzin Roman 18.09.2017 в 19:56. Присоединяйтесь!

Tags: поддержка, видеочат

С радостью спешу пригласить всех участников сообщества присоединиться к видеочату 18 сентября 2017 года в 19:56 по московскому времени. Гостями второго выпуска будут:

- [@Pavel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/224866/pavel), учился в Институте Культуры. На данный момент работает в компании First Line Software. Может часами рассказывать про джазовую жизнь Санкт–Петербурга.
- [@Rakzin Roman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191307/rakzin-roman), родился в Харькове, где окончил школу и университет, работал терапевтом. [С детства занимается музыкой и пением](https://www.youtube.com/user/RakzinRoman). На данный момент работает анестезиологом в Германии. В свободное от медицинской практики время, занимается программированием для автоматизации рабочих процессов.

Роман и Павел являются одними из тех участников, которые публикуют большое количество хороших вопросов, помогая сообществу формировать базу знаний. В течение выпуска у нас будет уникальная возможность пообщаться с ребятами, узнать, что является той движущей силой, которая питает их энергией для изучения программирования.

Видео будет доступно в реальном времени на канале сообщества: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbBYf0WwN4Y.

#### Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы гостям!

Как и ранее, главная цель видеочата – узнать друг друга поближе. Расскажите гостям о том, что вам интересно в них! Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы участникам выпуска!

Ваши вопросы участникам выпуска вы можете задать в [чате сообщества](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). Обязательно, задавая вопрос, упомяните `@NicolasChabanovsky` и/или имя участника, кому вопрос адресован , чтобы я (мы) мог своевременно отреагировать на ваш вопрос. Также вы можете отправить ваш вопрос к участникам заранее мне на почту (nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com) или опубликовать комментарием или ответом в данном вопросе.

С нетерпением ждем вас!

**Обновление**

В предверии выпуска, немного «о цифрах». На двоих Роман и Павел задали более 800 вопросов. К слову, всего у нас на сайте 164 тысячи вопросов, которые были заданы 38 тысячами участников, то есть в среднем это 4 вопроса от одного участника. Что на самом деле не до конца отражает действительность. В действительности

- У 27 тысяч участников, задающих вопросы, два или меньше вопроса.
- У 21 тысячи участников, лишь один вопрос.
- 6 тысяч участников задали более 4 вопросов каждый.
- 3 тысячи более 10 вопросов на человека.
- 117 участников более 100 каждый.
- Лишь 45 участников за все время существования сообщества задали по 150+ вопросов.

С предвкушением ждем встречи!

Comment: Анестезиолог-программист. Ух, я живу в будущем.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Каждый раз, когда лично знакомлюсь с кем–нибудь из сообщества, понимаю, какая скучная у меня жизнь и какие удивительные люди вокруг!

Comment: @NickVolynkin, был уже подобный персонаж, Con Kolivas, активно участвовавший в разработке ядра Linux.

Comment: Надо картинку с графиком и по степеням двойки :) Есть dataSE-запрос для допиливания?

Comment: @Qwertiy, судя по моей истории, я использовал вот этот запрос: https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/718795.

Comment: Ну вот... А я думал, там какой-нибудь интересный запрос с логарифмической группировкой.

Comment: Обратный отсчёт: 10 min.

Comment: 7 min и в чате уведомление у тех кто подписывался на ивент

Comment: 5 min..........

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/revision/724770/901483/2n--- - 2 resultset'а & https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/revision/724770/901490/2n--- - всё в одном

Comment: @Qwertiy Выглядит здорово! Спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, несколько напрягает 0 пользователей с 741 вопросом. Я правильно понимаю, что это число анонимных вопросов?

Comment: @Qwertiy С ходу не скажу, надо разбираться.